# How encrypt and decrypt a SAML assertion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, saml-2.0, okta

I am using Okta for SSO. I got a SAML response in HTML encode format. How can I encrypt the SAML assertion response from an Identity Provider and decrypt it on a Service Provider?

Comment: If you decide to use the ComponentSpace SAML v2.0 toolkit, I suggest taking a look at our [Okta Integration Guide](http://www.componentspace.com/Forums/5439/Okta-Integration).

Answer (score 2):

Okta supports encrypting SAML assertions. See Okta's [SAML 2.0 Encryption documentation](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/102619923-SAML-2-0-Encryption-Early-Access) for details.

As far as decrypting the assertions goes, the SAML library you should use depends on which .NET Framework you are using:

If you are using [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history) 4.5 or above, use [Kentor Authentication Services](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices#kentor-authentication-services), otherwise, for .NET Framework 4 or below, use [ComponentSpace SAML 2.0](http://www.componentspace.com/SAMLv20.aspx).

After selecting the appropriate SAML library, you'll need to consult the documentation to find how to configure the library with the key pair that you'll be using to decrypt encrypted SAML assertions.

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt SAML assertion from Okta (Identity Provider) you would need to go to General tab of your SAML app, edit the SAML setting, click show advanced settings and select Assertion Encryption to be Encrypted and select encryption and key transport algorithm based on your requirement.

[image]

On the service provider side you would need to configure your SAML toolkit to decrypt the SAML assertion. Configuration will vary for every toolkit. You will need to check documentation of toolkit you are using for how to do it.